# Cartesian parametrization of the Greek Meandre

Tags: geometry, fourier-analysis, parametric

As the title suggests, I've been trying to find a parametric equation to describe the Greek meander pattern that's seen in a lot of historical architecture.

I've created a series of X and Y coordinates that traces it out:
[image]

And I have both a set of quasiperiodic data describing the X values:
[image: X value over nth sample]

And a set of periodic data describing the Y values:
[image: Y value over nth sample]

How would I find the equation that describes these? At first I thought I had to do a Fourier  series but I wouldn't even know where to start with a function like this.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}$Although Roland's (+1) piecewise function is efficient and accurate, a sketch of setting up a Fourier transform may be useful to posterity.

The two component functions are (quasi-)periodic with period $16$, so we may as well work on the interval $[0, 16]$ with the inner product
$$
\Brak{f, g} = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{16} f(t)g(t)\, dt.
$$
The functions
$$
c_{0}(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\qquad
c_{k}(t) = \cos(2\pi kt/16),\quad
s_{k}(t) = \sin(2\pi kt/16)\ \text{for $k$ positive}
$$
form an orthonormal basis with respect to this inner product.

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the piecewise-linear component functions, and set $Z(t) = X(t) - t/4$, so that $Z$ and $Y$ are periodic with period $16$. Using numerical integration (perhaps Simpson's rule, dividing $[0, 16]$ into $16n$ subintervals), approximate the Fourier coefficients
$$
\widehat{Zc}_{k} = \Brak{Z, c_{k}},\quad
\widehat{Zs}_{k} = \Brak{Z, s_{k}},\qquad
\widehat{Yc}_{k} = \Brak{Y, c_{k}},\quad
\widehat{Ys}_{k} = \Brak{Y, s_{k}}
$$
for $0 \leq k \leq 4n$. (Formally, treat $s_{0} = 0$.) For the highest frequency terms, that gives four Simpson subdivision points per period.

Now we can reconstitute the approximate component functions:
$$
\widehat{X} = \frac{t}{4} + \sum_{k=0}^{4n} \widehat{Zc}_{k} c_{k} + \widehat{Zs}_{k} s_{k},\qquad
\widehat{Y} = \sum_{k=0}^{4n} \widehat{Yc}_{k} c_{k} + \widehat{Ys}_{k} s_{k},
$$
and plot the resulting parametric path.

As proof of concept, here's a plot with $n = 8$ ($128$ subdivisions for integrating, $32$ sine terms and $33$ cosine terms):

[image: Fourier transform of the Greek meandre]

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate the directions over line segments.  The result is

```
 X[t_] := 
   With[{s = Mod[t, 16], r = Floor[t, 16]}, 
   {r/4, 0} + 
   Piecewise[{
   {{0, s}, s <= 3}, 
    {{s - 3, 3}, s <= 6},
    {{3, 3 - (s - 6)}, s < 8}, 
    {{3 - (s - 8), 1}, s <= 9}, 
    {{2, 1 + (s - 9)}, s <= 10}, 
    {{2 - (s - 10), 2}, s <= 11}, 
    {{ 1, 2 - (s - 11)}, s <= 13}, 
    {{1 + s - 13, 0},s <= 16}, {0, 0} }]] 

    pic = ParametricPlot[X[t], {t, 0, 64}, 
             PlotStyle -> {Blue,Thickness[0.03]},  Axes -> None]
```

[image: Greek meander Santorini Blue]

Comment: This looks to be a Mathematica program. Could you confirm ?

Comment: Yes. A TeX equivalent, simplified, $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{-t,0\} & 8\leq (t \bmod 16)\leq 9\lor 10<(t \bmod 16)\leq 11 \\
 \{0,-t\} & 6<(t \bmod 16)<8\lor 11<(t \bmod 16)\leq 13 \\
 \{0,0\} & (t \bmod 16)>13 \\
 \{0,t\} & 9<(t \bmod 16)\leq 10\lor (t \bmod 16)\leq 3 \\
 \{t,0\} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\frac{1}{4} \text{Floor}[t,16]$$

Comment: Please have a look at my answer providing a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add my little stone to the building, even it is not an answer to the question about a parametric plot.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Basic pattern $B$ in red. Symmetrical pattern in green.*

@Andrew D. Hwang has shown that Fourier analysis could be involved in a natural way in this issue.

I would like here to show that **discrete convolution** (with a coding of the moves by **complex numbers**) has also a natural place in this issue.

The generation of the greek meander pattern shown on fig. 1 has been generated by the following Matlab program :

> ```
> n=5;                           % number of repetitions
> B=[0,3i,6,-4i,-2,i];           % (red relative moves) 
> C=[B,fliplr(B)];               % (red + green rel. moves)
> DC=repmat([1,zeros(1,8)],1,n); % Dirac comb
> D=conv(C,DC);                  % (red + green + blue rel. moves)
> GM=cumsum(D);                  % (relative -> absolute moves)
> plot(GM);
> ```

Comments : I have taken into account the fact that the greek meander has **a central symmetry** ; function "fliplr" (flip left-right) realizes this symmetry. Besides "repmat" (repeat matrix) operates the following repetition :

$$DC=[1,\underbrace{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}_{\text{eight times}},1,\underbrace{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}_{\text{eight times}},1,0,0,\cdots],$$

The final operation, convolution by a (discrete) Dirac comb, gives the periodization.